# Using subset on dates giving shifted dates from the desired time frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame (called homeAnew) from which the head is as follows.

```
date                   total
1 2014-01-01 00:00:00  0.756
2 2014-01-01 01:00:00  0.717
3 2014-01-01 02:00:00  0.643
4 2014-01-01 03:00:00  0.598
5 2014-01-01 04:00:00  0.604
6 2014-01-01 05:00:00  0.638
```

I wanted to extract explicit dates and I originally used:

```
Hourly <- subset(homeAnew,date >= "2014-04-10 00:00:00" & date <= "2015-04-10 00:00:00")
```

However the result was a dataframe that started at 2014-04-09 12:00:00 and ended 2015-04-09 12:00:00. Basically it was shifted back 12 hours from where I wanted it.
I was able to use

```
Date1<-as.Date("2014-04-10 00:00:00")
Date2<-as.Date("2015-04-10 00:00:00")
Hourly<-homeAnew[homeAnew$date>=Date1 & homeAnew$date<=Date2,]
```

To get what was after but I was wondering if someone could explain to me why subset would work like that?

Comment: To be able to perform logical operations with date and times, you will need to use a POSIXlt format, e.g. `as.POSIXlt("2014-04-10 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: does `date` have a timezone attached?

Comment: extending @Roman Lustrik answer you may use this to produce desired effect.

`Hourly <- subset(homeAnew,date >= as.Date("2014-04-10 00:00:00") & date <= as.Date("2015-04-10 00:00:00"))`

Comment: Thanks @AkarshJain that worked.Can't believe that I didn't think to try that. I was using the POSIXct format and yes I believe it does have a timezone attached because a previous function (openair::timeAverage) insisted on converting it to UTC.

Comment: No problem :) @Musketeered